# How to omit returning the rows for "false" values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet with multiple tabs.  The first tab is the master sheet and columns A-G contain identifying data.  In the second tab I have created a formula to return the value in column A of the master sheet if the value in column H is greater than Z.

The problem with the formula that I created is that it will also return all of the blank rows if column H is not greater than 0. How do I create a formula that will skip / not return the "false" rows?

Comment: I basically understand what you want, without knowing how you are doing this the best answer is going to use the IF function. `=IF(condition, value if true, value if false).  Edit your question with an EXACT formula that you are using, and I'll write an answer.

Comment: =IF(H1<>"",<Your formula here>)

Comment: We need to see your formula so we can help you.

Comment: Take a look at [this website](http://exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/) which uses formulas to filter a table.  Unfortunately excel doesn't have an easy way to do this like google docs

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF('Master Sheet'!H2>Z, 'Master Sheet'!A2, "")
```

> =IF(condition, value if true, value if false)

condition =  if the value in column H is greater than *Z*
If True      =  If true, return the value in A2 (starting at A2, assuming you have a header row)
If False    =  If false, return a blank cell. I like to return a dash so I use "-", this way I know something was calculated.

This of course will result in having rows populated and blank, but a simple sort will bring your results to the top.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I believe the purpose is to not end up with a bunch of blank rows (which this returns)  It sounds like he is looking for a filter more than an if statement.

Comment: of course you could always try the formula below if you include a row number collumn in row A and push your data along.